# Is there a possibility to access class method out of a nested handler method in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I want to send a XMLHttpRequest to a server with JavaScript. Within the handler function I need to call a method of the surrounding class. Is there a way to realize this?

I know the usage of `this` in JavaScript is a little bit tricky. So I tried out all permutations of using `this` and `bind(this)`, but with no success.

```js
class ServerRequest
{
    askServer(url)
    {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                // Got the response
                this.foo().bind(this); // How to access foo-method??
            }
        }
        request.open('GET', url);
        request.send();
    }

    foo()
    {
        // Do something here
    }
}
```

My aim is just to reach this foo method, but Firefox Console shows me the message "TypeError: this.foo is not a function".

Comment: `foo.call(ServerRequest);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could handle it in two ways.

**Use the arrow function**

```
askServer(url)
{
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            // Got the response
            this.foo(); // How to access foo-method??
        }
    }
    request.open('GET', url);
    request.send();
}

foo()
{
    // Do something here
}
```

As you can see I'm now referencing request object by variable and not by `this` since arrow function scope is bound differently.
And you can see here how you can reference request:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange#Example

**Save upper scope reference in variable**:

```
askServer(url)
{
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var self = this;
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            // Got the response
            self.foo(); // How to access foo-method??
        }
    }
    request.open('GET', url);
    request.send();
}

foo()
{
    // Do something here
}
```